# xcode open "click here to view symbol declaration" in same window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, ios

Is there a way to configure xcode to prevent quick help from opening "click here to view symbol declaration" in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you code directly in the project explorer?  If you switch to coding in the popped up window, you can select the "grouped/ungrouped" button so it shows grouped.  That should keep all your popped up windows in one place, *but* you're not coding in the explorer anymore.

Pick your poison!